# fullwidth environment with sidenotes package

Tags: scrbook, sidenotes

How to have fullwidth text. Odd page result is not expected one. Even page result is correct.

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
%,bindingoffset=30pt
,asymmetric
,reversemarginpar
,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
% fullwidth environment, text across textwidth+marginparsep+marginparwidth
\newlength{\overhang}
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}
%
\newenvironment{fullwidth}
  {\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}%
     {\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\overhang}}%
     {\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\overhang}}%
  }%
  {\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}%
    {\end{adjustwidth*}}%
    {\end{adjustwidth}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
%\secion{hh}
\minisec{hh}
\blindtext
\end{fullwidth}

\clearpage

\begin{fullwidth}
%\secion{hh}
\minisec{hh}
\blindtext
\end{fullwidth}


\end{document}
```

> Wrong Odd page

[image]

> Even page results are correct

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by fullwidth? The total width of the paper format?

Comment: Your code does not compile here.

Comment: You need to add `ifthen`. However, I'm not at all clear what the expected output is or what exactly you are doing. You are loading multiple packages which are vying for control of the page layout. `scrbook` is loading `typearea` etc. and you are passing it options asking for double-sided with no switching of margins. Then you are layering `geometry` on top of that which will override the existing layout. Finally `sidenotes` is further complicating things. It would be cleaner to use the facilities of `scrbook` and the associated layout packages instead of `geometry`, minimising complications.

Comment: If you do really need `geometry`, have you considered using e.g. `\newgeometry`?

Comment: You do not need the `\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}` stuff, you can use `adjustwidth*` environment also in oneside mode (there exist only right pages then). Note, that there is also a KOMA-Script own environment `addmargin⟨*⟩` with the same functionality. Read `sidenotes` and `changepage` documentation for package option `strict`. You could also take a look on the KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-notecolumn`.

Comment: @cfr fullwidth=textwidth+marginparsep+marginparwidth I want to have text to fullwidth.

Comment: I do not know how to create fullwidth environment using "adjustwidth" or "addmargin". See my answer below.

Comment: So this is solved?

Comment: Yes, It works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solution from  **Speravir** using adjustwidth* environment

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage} 

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
%,bindingoffset=30pt
,asymmetric
,reversemarginpar
,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
% fullwidth environment, text across textwidth+marginparsep+marginparwidth
\newlength{\overhang}
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\blindtext

\begin{adjustwidth*}{-\overhang}{}  
\section{One-one}
\blindtext
\end{adjustwidth*}

\clearpage

\begin{adjustwidth*}{-\overhang}{}  
\section{One-two}
\blindtext
\end{adjustwidth*}

\end{document}
```

> Solution from  **Speravir** using addmargin* environment (KOMA-Script specific)

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage} 

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
%,bindingoffset=30pt
,asymmetric
,reversemarginpar
,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
% fullwidth environment, text across textwidth+marginparsep+marginparwidth
\newlength{\overhang}
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\blindtext

\begin{addmargin*}[-\overhang]{0em}
\section{One-one}
\blindtext
\end{addmargin*}

\clearpage

\begin{addmargin*}[-\overhang]{0em}
\section{One-two}
\blindtext
\end{addmargin*}

\end{document}
```